# Stop form validation submitting if error on file upload

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Question:** When the user has filled in the form validation correct but there is a **error on image upload** how is it possible to stop the form being submitted

Currently still submits data even if there is a error on my image upload.

```
<?php

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('countries');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->model('admin/user/user_model');
        $this->load->model('admin/user_group/usergroup_model');
    }

    public function add() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
                if (!is_dir(FCPATH . 'uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/')) {
                    mkdir(FCPATH . 'uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/');
                }

                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png';
                $config['max_size'] = 3000;
                $config['max_width'] = 0;
                $config['max_height'] = 0;
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            $this->user_model->insert($this->upload->data());
        }

        if ($this->upload->display_errors() != false) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

        if (validation_errors() != false) {
            $this->error['warning'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['warning_error'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['warning_error'] = '';
        }

        $data['countries'] = $this->countries->get();
        $data['timezones'] = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
        $data['usergroups'] = $this->usergroup_model->get_user_groups();
        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('user/add_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function insert($upload_data = array()) {
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
        ];

        $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

        $data = array(
            'user_group_id' => $this->input->post('user_group_id'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $hash,
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'image' => ($upload_data['file_name']) ? $upload_data['file_name'] : '',
            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
            'timezone' => $this->input->post('timezone'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'date_added' => date('Y-m-d')
        );

        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
        } 
    }
}
```

Codeigniter Version 3.1.0 & XAMPP Windows 10

Comment: try, if (validation_errors() != '') {
            $this->error['warning'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
        }

Comment: validation_errors() will return any error messages sent back by the validator. If there are no messages it returns an empty string.

Comment: Did not work. When the form is correct but error on file upload should trigger form to be stopped.

Comment: All the code for file upload should be kept in else part of, if (validation_errors() != ''){ }else{ put file upload code here};

Answer (score 0):

Have solved it now.

```
<?php

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('countries');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->model('admin/user/user_model');
        $this->load->model('admin/user_group/usergroup_model');
    }

    public function add() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|is_unique[user.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Opps looks like someone has all ready got that {field}');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {

                if ($this->upload() == true) {
                    $this->user_model->insert($this->upload->data());
                }

            } else {

                $this->user_model->insert();
            }
        }

        if (validation_errors() != '') { 
            $this->error['warning'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); 
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['warning_error'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['warning_error'] = '';
        }

        $data['countries'] = $this->countries->get();
        $data['timezones'] = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
        $data['usergroups'] = $this->usergroup_model->get_user_groups();
        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('user/add_view', $data);
    }

    public function upload() {
        if (!is_dir(FCPATH . 'uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/')) {
            mkdir(FCPATH . 'uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/');
        }

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/users/' . $this->input->post('username') . '/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 3000;
        $config['max_width'] = 0;
        $config['max_height'] = 0;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out of usernames for creating directories' names. Directories' names shouldn't content anything other than letters and numbers or you could run into unpredictable issues. Easiest way would be to add `alpha_numeric` rule to username field or work around on some other solution.

Comment: Thanks for tip will look into it